# Spring boot: how to disable session handler for the embedded server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty, spring-session

Our application does not need any session support but Spring adds session handler and a session id managed to the embedded Jetty server. I tried removing the handler in the server customizer but then spring context won't start.
Any way to get this removed(or disable session)?

Comment: Don't use sessions then. If you are using Spring Security set it to STATELESS. If you are using JSPs disable it in the pages. Also if you added `spring-session` as a dependency why did you add it as that is explicitly for session support.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I think Spring is creating the embedded Jetty server using its WebAppContext, the root cause is that during the initialization this `getSessionHandler` is called  
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/d4d8832b11f02bd334b42af07f598ce904bf7736/jetty-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.java#L416
I'd like to have this set to null but then spring won't start. This is just a mean my goal is to have minimum overhead for features I don't use.